# Selecting child elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to quickly select an element on my page using jQuery. This is the code so far:

```
$('#row-58708 > div.cell name > div > strong').html('tesing');
```

This is the markup:

```
<div id="row-58708" class="row">
    <div class="cell name">
        <div>
            <strong>Skin name</strong>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I know what I've written is far off the mark, but I can't work it out anyhow... could anyone lend a hand? Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

You're actually not far off, you're just not using the multiple class selector correctly:

```
$('#row-58708 > div.cell.name > div > strong').html('tesing');
```

In your version, you have `div.cell name`, which literally means "select all `name` tags that are within a div of class cell." Of course, there is no name tag, but you see the point.

Comment: somehow i never noticed the right arrow notation before -- this is a huge help (and clearer to look at that dot notation too)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.row').find('strong').html('tesing');
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/gZA8E/

Answer (score 0):

I take it you want to change **Skin name** to **testing**.  If so use this:

```
$('#row-58708 strong').html('testing')
```